# Looping through validation checks, and return false if one of the checks returns false?

Tags: php, loops, methods, boolean

Im trying to figure out a way to loop through objects with a validation method that returns true or false, and then in the end know if any of the object returned false.

```
    $validate_form = true;

    //Loop through groups
    foreach ($this->field_groups as $field_group) {


        //Loop through fields
        foreach ($field_group->fields as $field) {


            $validated = $field->validate($data[$field->name]);
            //if any of these returned false, set $validate_form to false

        }

    }

    return $validate_form;
```

But i simply can't rap my head around how to achieve this. I have thought about using an array, and then check if any of the values in the array has 'false' in it. But that seems a bit clumsy.

I feel like there must be a "best practice" on how to do this?

UPDATE: Its important that each field runs the `->validate()` method. even fields that comes after the first "false".

Thanks!

Comment: So, what is wrong with the *exact* code that you have written in the question? That seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Why does it matter that all the validate methods run?

Comment: @Sammitch : My code will never return false, since thats never set. Also if i did use the method to return the value of $validate_form then the result will just be whatever the last method returns

Comment: @Hammerstein : Because the method sets some properties (error message) when run. these are used later in the script. But if I don't run the method on all of them, then some of these error won't be set.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with this :

```
$validate_form = true;

//Loop through groups
foreach ($this->field_groups as $field_group) {


    //Loop through fields
    foreach ($field_group->fields as $field) {


        $validated = $field->validate($data[$field->name]);
        //if any of these returned false, set $validate_form to false
        if (!$validated)
        {
            $validate_form = false;
            break;
        }
    }

}

return $val_form;
```

The "break;" is going to stop the loop.

Comment: I do need all the field to run the validate method though.

Comment: Well then you could save the result of every validation in an array and after your loops loop through the whole array and check if any value is "false".

Comment: Yeah - that was the solution I suggested in the question too - but does that not feel a bit clumsy?